# styled component global class strategy

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

What's the best or elegant strategy to use a global class using styled-components? I can create a component and style it, import it when I need it. For instance

```
const CenterStyled = styled.div`
   align-item: center;
   display: flex;
`
export default const Center = ({children}) => <CenterStyled>{children}</Center>
```

Is there any npm package or helper utils I can already use? or there's other better way to do it?

Comment: A global class like reusable class or as the className available from all instances?

Comment: @DennisVash that's also one of the way, but styled component is trying to get rid of using class names.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what does global class means in your context, maybe you can show a snippet of the desired behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a repeated style you want to reuse, typically you define a `mixins` file and import the `css` blocks:

```
// mixins.js
import { css } from "styled-components";

const flexAlignCenter = css`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
`;
const flexAlignStart = css`
  ${flexAlignCenter}
  align-items: flex-start;
`;

const mixins = { flexAlignCenter, flexAlignStart };
export default mixins;
```

```
// Usage
import { mixins } from '@styles'; // Some styles alias
const Container = styled.div`
  ${mixins.flexAlignCenter}
`;
const Component = ({ children }) => <Container>{children}</Container>;
```

> You can see ["real world" example here](https://github.com/kube-HPC/dashboard/blob/master/src/styles/mixins.styles.js) (some paid project I work on).

Comment: nice, this is clean too, merely use javascript object to store 'variable'